# google app engine for java- using low level API to fetch data- some difficulties

Tags: java, google-app-engine, xml-rpc

In a Google App Engine for Java web app, I am trying to use the low level api to invoke an XML RPC ...After looking at the docs, I figured out the following code to connect using low level API-the reason why I want to use Low Level API is so that I can set the timeout value myself--

```
         String mrtime="120";
         java.lang.Double maxresponsetime;
         maxresponsetime = Double.valueOf(mrtime).doubleValue();
         HTTPRequest req=  new  HTTPRequest(url, HTTPMethod.GET, disallowTruncate().setDeadline(maxresponsetime));
         HTTPResponse response= com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.URLFetchServiceFactory.getURLFetchService().fetch(req);
         String line="";
         String resp="";
         resp=new String(response.getContent(), "UTF-8");
```

The above code is suitable for a scenario where the remote URL is accessed by GAE...However I have to also send an XML message containing name of function as well as input parameters (these are stored in variable named 'message')... How do I send that message to the remote URL, and after that obtain the response?

Answer (score 2):

You should post the call method and parameters instead of GET. The method name and parameters go as XML.

See this http://xmlrpc.scripting.com/spec.html

Comment: @SidMalani- i have stored the method name and parameters in a single variable (to go as XML)...However here I dont have the URL Connection object...I only have the request and response... how do I send the method name and parameters in this case? Thanks...

Comment: But with setPayload use POST rather than GET.

Comment: @SidMalani-  I am using the following code to send payload with POST request-- HTTPRequest req=  new  HTTPRequest(url, HTTPMethod.POST, disallowTruncate().setDeadline(maxresponsetime));  byte[] payload = message.getBytes();   req.setPayload(payload);   HTTPResponse response= com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.URLFetchServiceFactory.getURLFetchService().fetch(req);---However I am not getting desired response.., kindly tell me (if possible) what I am doing wrong here... Thanks...

Comment: Have you tried changing the timeout? Try increasing it and see if you get a response. Do you get any error codes?